# When creating (not running) a docker, does assigning a container to a network have any real effect?

Tags: mysql, docker

When i create a container (but not run it yet) by `docker container create ...` (not by `docker run`), if I include option `--network my_network_name` then when i run this docker, will the docker be connected to the network that i specified?
If you say 'no' then it means `--network my_network_name` does not have any real effect.

More specifically, if i create a container by:

```
docker container create --name mysql_container --network my_network mysql
```

then when i run it by:

```
docker container start -it mysql_container
```

will `mysql_container` be automatically connected to `my_network`?

Comment: `will mysql_container be automatically connected to my_network?` did you try it? I mean that question is something that can be easily tested yourself. If you observe that this is the or is not the case, you could ask why it does not work, or if it is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score -2):

from Docker. Docs

Network drivers

Docker’s networking subsystem is pluggable, using drivers. Several drivers exist by default, and provide core networking functionality:

**bridge**: The default network driver. If you don’t specify a driver, this is the type of network you are creating. Bridge networks are usually used when your applications run in standalone containers that need to communicate. See bridge networks.

**host:** For standalone containers, remove network isolation between the container and the Docker host, and use the host’s networking directly. See use the host network.

**overlay**: Overlay networks connect multiple Docker daemons together and enable swarm services to communicate with each other. You can also use overlay networks to facilitate communication between a swarm service and a standalone container, or between two standalone containers on different Docker daemons. This strategy removes the need to do OS-level routing between these containers. See overlay networks.

**macvlan**: Macvlan networks allow you to assign a MAC address to a container, making it appear as a physical device on your network. The Docker daemon routes traffic to containers by their MAC addresses. Using the macvlan driver is sometimes the best choice when dealing with legacy applications that expect to be directly connected to the physical network, rather than routed through the Docker host’s network stack. See Macvlan networks.

**none**: For this container, disable all networking. Usually used in conjunction with a custom network driver. none is not available for swarm services. See disable container networking.

**Network plugins**: You can install and use third-party network plugins with Docker. These plugins are available from Docker Hub or from third-party vendors. See the vendor’s documentation for installing and using a given network plugin.

Comment: And how does this answer the question? The question is what effect ` --network my_network mysql` will have when used with `docker create`.